# Place text at the very top shinydashboard sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In the `shiny` app below I would like to put the text that is inside the sidebar a little bit higher than it is in order to be in the same line with the tab panel tabs. The header is disabled and the `tabsetPabel()` should not be moved lower instead.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  dashboardSidebar(
    h4("titletitletilte")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id="inTabset",
      tabPanel("show",
      ),
      tabPanel("Hide")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
h4(style = "position: absolute;top: 15px;", "titletitletilte")
```

Comment: yes exactly but more alinged in the center instead of left

Comment: You can learn a lot about `CSS` (because it is essentailly what we are using here) at https://www.w3schools.com/css/.